# Azure Cdn Custom Domain with GoDaddy

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn, godaddy-api

Based on the microsoft tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain

I have created 2 **CNAME** record in GoDaddy:

Host: **test1.agi-ltd.net**

Points to: **test1.azureedge.net**

Host: **test2.agi-ltd.net**

Points to: **test2.azureedge.net**

And in azure CDN profile i have created 2 endpoint:

**test1.azureedge.net**

**test2.azureedge.net**

What I trying to do was to add custom domain for each of the end point so for
**test1.azureedge.net** i wanted to add **test1.agi-ltd.net** as custom domain
but it keep showing me error "**cannot find DNS record / CNAME record for test1.azureedge.net that points to test1.agi-ltd.net**"

But I have added in the domain DNS page already

Anyone can help this? Did I miss out something or set up anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I run into exactly this problem, did you find a solution?